# How to define a method that can return a DataTable or List <T>?

Tags: c#, interface, datatable, generic-collections

I am trying to define a generic method that can return a list of data. I want to make it flexible to allow to return a DataTable or List<T>. 
e.g.

```cs
 *SomeGenericDataTypeInterface* GetResult(IDictionary IDictParams);
```

There does not seem to be any base interface common to DataTable and List. Is this possible at all ?

Comment: You could use object, but it may be wiser to just write two different methods to make it more explicit and typed.

Comment: And what is benefit of having such single method? Caller anyway should know what will be returned.

Answer (score 5):

You will need two different methods, one returning a DataTable the other returning the List. While there may be ways (like some suggested), best practice is to have two methods each returning an explicit type.

Answer (score 0):

Define the output as `object`. But it would be very general

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `dynamic` keyword i.e.

```
public dynamic GetResult(IDictionary IDictParams)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DataTable and List inherits from `object` type, so return an object type instead. In the calling method, you can check the return type as `if(result is DataTable){//do this}`.